# Item selected automatically

Tags: java, android

How can I have an item ("R.id.nav_code" for example) automatically selected when I open a page ?

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
if (id == R.id.nav_code) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new code())
            .commit();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_documentation) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new documentation())
            .commit();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_number) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new number())
            .commit();
}
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: do you want to start new fragment when your activity starts?

Comment: Yes (Sorry for my english, I'm French).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start default fragment everytime your activity start then add this code into your activity `onCreate` Method

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout);

FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
code_Fragment code=new code_Fragment(); //Create Object Of your Fragment
transaction.replace(R.id.FragmentLoginRegistration,code);
transaction.commit();
}
```